# I did not find a way to add loading and loading-text to Vuexy Vdatatable

Tags: vuejs3

this is my attempt to show loading and loading-text, but this is not working

```js
<VDataTable
            :headers="headers"
            :items="Object.values(policies)"
            :items-per-page="1000"
            expand-on-click
            loading
            loading-text="Loading..."
          >
```